# iPhone Objective-C: Select from table and diplay selected ones in the style of the "To:" part of iPhone's SMS, email, etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to be able to select items from a table and display them like how the iPhone displays the list of recipients for SMS, email, etc. It would be great if you could lead me to any resources and/or direction for this kind of thing. (I wasn't really sure how to Google this kind of thing too.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the interface with each email address in a little bubble, and they get highlighted if you hit backspace and deleted if you hit backspace again, it's kind of complicated to reproduce (I've done it). This is partly because (at least prior to iOS4) the way you interact with the keyboard is a bit limited. You need to have a hidden space character at the beginning of your `UITextField` to even get a call when the user hits backspace when there are no other characters left.

As for creating the table that shows the addresses from the user's address book, use a standard `UITableView` and do yourself a favor and use Erica Sadun's [address book utilities](http://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper) to get the data from the address book.

There is something very similar in [the Three20 framework](http://github.com/facebook/three20), so I'd suggest you have a look at that.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Those little bubbles. Thank you!